# How to refactor a repeated switch to filter different calls

Tags: java, switch-statement, repository, refactoring

I have several methods on my service that call different Spring Data automatic repository methods. How can i refactor this code? It smells everywhere!

```
public List<SupportMessages> findByProduct(Product product, Status status) {
  Date date = new Date();
  switch(status) {
    case EXPIRED:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByProductAndDateAfter(product, date);
    case VALID:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByProductAndDateBefore(product, date);
    case ALL:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByProduct(product);  
}


public List<SupportMessages> findByRegion(Region region, Status status) {
  Date date = new Date();
  switch(status) {
    case EXPIRED:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByRegionAndDateAfter(region, date);
    case VALID:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByRegionAndDateBefore(region, date);
    case ALL:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByRegion(region);  
}

public List<SupportMessages> findByClient(Client client, Status status) {
  Date date = new Date();
  switch(status) {
    case EXPIRED:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByClientAndDateAfter(client, date);
    case VALID:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByClientAndDateBefore(client, date);
    case ALL:
      return supportMessageRepository.findByClient(client);  
}
```

Comment: The methods that or being called within the `switch` all seem to resolve differently, in that case, this is about as good as it gets. An alternative pattern is to implement these `findX` methods in the `Status` enum itself.

Comment: Can you please clarify which of the classes and methods shown you control (i.e., you could refactor or rename)?

Comment: @PNS I could refactor all classes, even the repository methods. Are the repositories the biggest problem?

Comment: Is the supportMessageRepository a singleton? Can you rename its methods?

Comment: @PNS Yes, I'm using Spring and is annotated with `@Autowired`. As far as I know, when using `@Autowired` Spring injects a singleton object.

Comment: @amateur yes, by default it is